# How to connect confluent cloud to databricks

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks, confluent-cloud

I want to know how to connect confluent cloud to databricks. I wantto read data from confluent to spark dataframe.

I have used this code:

```
df = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", confluentBootstrapserver) \
  .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SSL") \
  .option("subscribe", confluentTopic) \
  .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
  .option("kafka.sasl.jaas.config",
  "kafkashaded.org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
   username\"**********\" password = \"******************************\";").load()
```

i have used API key in username and secret in password. and provided topic name in confluentTopic.

i am getting various types of error "
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: kafkashaded.org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: describeTopics".
before that i was getting consumer can not be created.
I am new to this so please elaborate on your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code blocks.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
confluentBootstrapserver = "your_bootstrao_server"
confluentTopic = "topic_0"
apiKey="api_key"
apiSecret="api_secret"
```

Create new key in your cluster tab as below.

[image]

Copy and save the Api key and secret.

Next, you need to give these key and secret in `kafka.sasl.jaas.config`  spark option instead of giving username and password as below.
I think you given the same and it worked in my environment.

```
df = spark.readStream \
        .format("kafka") \
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", confluentBootstrapserver) \
        .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_SSL") \
        .option("kafka.sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN") \
        .option("kafka.sasl.jaas.config", f'kafkashaded.org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="{apiKey}" password="{apiSecret}";') \
        .option("subscribe", confluentTopic) \
        .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
        .load()
```

Next, create a function to get results from binary type and do udf register.

```
def conv_bin(x):
    import base64
    import json
    j = json.loads(base64.b64decode(str(x)).decode('utf-8'))
    return j
    
get_string = udf(conv_bin, StringType())
```

Display the results.

```
display(df.withColumn("key",get_string(base64(col("key")))).withColumn("result",get_string(base64(col("value")))).select("key","result","topic"))
```

Output:

[image]

and in spark

[image]

Check whether you giving correct port `9092`,
may be you batch data is too large or there may be problem with access to databricks from confluent.